# Conf swatches dont switch the product images

Tags: configurable-product

even though I've copied all the files needed from rwd theme to my theme, and swatches are displaying and are clickable, they do not switch the product images, and I've already compared conf swatches files from rwd and my theme and they are the same. I presume that java script is needed here.

Comment: If the files are not going to be edited, it would be better in most instances to have your theme inherit from RWD and NOT copy the files over unless you are editing them.

Do you have any plugins that are modifying the product image display?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to me, and detailed out how I tracked down the issue and what I had to do to fix it. Take a look, and ask any questions that you might have.

[Configurable product image not switching with swatch change](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132939/configurable-product-image-not-switching-with-swatch-change)